# Validate an API response against JSON schema using AJV

Tags: javascript, rest, jsonschema, web-api-testing, ajv

I have many days reading a lot and doing several tests with this, without the expected results.
I need validate an API response with its JSON schema (Swagger 2.0). The JSON is longer but I've reduced it to simply. I need to know if "code" and "message" keywords in the response have the type and values defined. Here the code I'm using:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv();

var schema = {
  "host": "cert",
  "paths": {
    "products": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "401": {
            "description": "Problem with the client request",
            "headers": {
              "x-correlator": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "uuid",
                "description": "Correlation id"
              }
            },
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "file:///../errors.json#/definitions/Unauthenticated"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "products": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "401": {
            "description": "Problem with the client request",
            "headers": {
              "x-correlator": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "uuid",
                "description": "Correlation id"
              }
            },
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "file:///../errors.json#/definitions/Unauthenticated"
            },
            "examples": {
              "application/json": {
                "code": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
                "message": "Authentication error"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var errors_schema = {
  "info": {
    "description": "Common errors",
    "version": "3.0.1",
    "title": "Common errors",
    "contact": {
      "name": "Team"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "ModelError": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "message"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "A human readable description"
        }
      }
    },
    "Unauthenticated": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "code"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "code": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "UNAUTHENTICATED"
              ],
              "default": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
              "description": "Request not authenticated due to missing, invalid, or expired credentials."
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ModelError"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

ajv.addSchema(errors_schema, 'file:///../errors.json');
var testajv = ajv.compile(schema);

var response = {"code": 123, "message":"token expired"}

var valid = testajv(response);

console.log(valid);

if(!valid) {
    console.log(testajv.errors);
}
```

As you see the keyword "code" in the response is '123' integer but in the schema it is defined as string. Independently of the value the validation  always gets 'true'. What should I do to get my needs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger schema contains multiple JSON schemas organized in API structure, you need to address a correct part of Swagger schema to employ JSON schema for validation.

Please check example code (https://runkit.com/embed/bwj42juwyjo4):

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv();

var schema = {
  "host": "cert",
  "paths": {
    "products": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "401": {
            "description": "Problem with the client request",
            "headers": {
              "x-correlator": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "uuid",
                "description": "Correlation id"
              }
            },
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "errors.json#/definitions/Unauthenticated"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "products": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "401": {
            "description": "Problem with the client request",
            "headers": {
              "x-correlator": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "uuid",
                "description": "Correlation id"
              }
            },
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "errors.json#/definitions/Unauthenticated"
            },
            "examples": {
              "application/json": {
                "code": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
                "message": "Authentication error"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var errors_schema = {
  "info": {
    "description": "Common errors",
    "version": "3.0.1",
    "title": "Common errors",
    "contact": {
      "name": "Team"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "ModelError": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "message"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "A human readable description"
        }
      }
    },
    "Unauthenticated": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "code"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "code": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "UNAUTHENTICATED"
              ],
              "default": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
              "description": "Request not authenticated due to missing, invalid, or expired credentials."
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ModelError"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

ajv.addSchema(errors_schema, 'errors.json');
ajv.addSchema(schema, 'swagger.json')



var testajv = ajv.compile({ $ref: 'errors.json#/definitions/Unauthenticated' });

console.log(testajv({"code": 123, "message":"token expired"}), testajv.errors); // Fails

console.log(testajv({"code": "AAA", "message":"token expired"}), testajv.errors); // Fails

console.log(testajv({"code": "UNAUTHENTICATED", "message":"token expired"}), testajv.errors); // Passes

var testajv2 = ajv.compile({ $ref: 'swagger.json#/paths/products/get/responses/401/schema' });

console.log(testajv2({"code": 123, "message":"token expired"}), testajv2.errors); // Fails

console.log(testajv2({"code": "AAA", "message":"token expired"}), testajv2.errors); // Fails

console.log(testajv2({"code": "UNAUTHENTICATED", "message":"token expired"}), testajv2.errors); // Passes
```

Some more information in relevant `ajv` issue: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/195

Comment: Thanks @vearutop, it works! Regarding I see, the two ajv.compile you used are trying to show me two ways for the same, right? Then, my swagger json file is longer than the exposed here, with several HTML response numbers (200, 400, 401, 503...). So, should I compile every HTML response number schema?

Comment: And finally (may be it is to open a new question, tell me in that case to do it). The real name of the keyword I mentioned as "products" is "/users/{user_id}/products". How can I write that in the compile function? I tried escaping the '/' and '{}' with '\' but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, two `ajv.compile` are just to show two ways of reaching your schema.

You need a separate validator instance (`ajv.compile`) for each schema, so if you want to validate multiple types of response, you need multiple validators.
Optionally you can use `ajv.validate(schema, data)` instead, but compiling and reusing validator will likely improve performance.

JSON Pointer requires escaping of `~` => `~0` and `/` => `~1` (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901#section-3). So your `/users/{user_id}/products` ref would be `~1users~1{user_id}~1products`.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. It works! I have open a new question related with it. May be you can help me as well there.

Answer (score 0):

Use type as number instead of string in code property.

```
"properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "number",
          "enum": [
            "UNAUTHENTICATED"
          ],
          "default": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
          "description": "Request not authenticated due to missing, invalid, or expired credentials."
        }
      }
```

Comment: I've tried that, but same output, "true", for response with "code": 123 or "code": "UNAUTHENTICATED".